# PageRenderer in Controller

Tags: grails

Can we implement PageRender in controller (grails 3.2.8)? I tried in a service and it worked perfectly as expected.
But when I tried in a controller, I am not getting the expected results.

Controller:

```
class TestcontrollerController {
    def RenderService
    def gsp= "grails"
    PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer

    def index(String gsp) {
        render creategsp()
    }

    def creategsp() {
        groovyPageRenderer.render view: '/email/confirm', model: [gsp: findgsp()]
    }

    def findgsp() {
        '<g:select from="${18..65}" value="${age}" />'
    }
}
```

index.gsp:

```
<g:render template="/test/samplePage" />
```

samplePage.gsp:

```
<g:render template="/email/welcome" />
```

_display.gsp:

```
Hi ,{username} <br>
```

PageRenderer is not rendering any of the custom tags or grails tags.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try and what were the unexpected results?

Comment: Hi Doelleri, I have updated the post. Customs tag or grails tags are not rendered when passed through the method using PageRenderer.

Comment: I am not sure, what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is completely possible.  Just define it at the top of your controller:

```
PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer
```

Note that you need to strongly type this, and not just "def" it.

Then when you use it, it will render pages to strings:

```
String renderViewResult = groovyPageRenderer.render(view: "/myViewName", model: renderModel)
```

If you update your question with more details like what you did, and what isn't working, possibly someone can help you more, but big picture: yep, it works!